# Questions from before the split that are now on MSE should respond with a 301 instead of a 302

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mso-mse-split

An example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/16065 responds with a 302 Found.

The spec says this is a temporary redirect. (Browsers treat it as a 303 See Other but that's irrelevant I think.) This causes the links to appear in Google when searching for `foo site:meta.stackoverflow.com` making it a lot harder to find a duplicate that is actually on MSO.

Responding with a 301 Moved Permanently should fix this.

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: What if a question is migrated back?

Comment: Then MSE will respond with 301 but MSO not. I guess it might work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has now been implemented.

When redirecting from an old MSO post to MSE, the redirect will be a permanent one.

With you in the next build. rev 2014.8.22.1792, meta rev 2014.8.22.2477

Comment: The 301 pages are still appearing in the search results; [this answer on Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/61007/21304) conflicts with what I found during initial research, it says the pages are never removed from the results, they just drop in ranking. So I guess unfortunately we're stuck with the current situation.